# Is there an adjective for "originating and persisting continuously until now"?

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm looking for a word that would fit the space below:

> Even as a(n) [adjective] city-dweller, I recognize the importance of the haystacks.

I have searched to no avail and restructured the sentence in case no such word exists, but I'm still curious and would love to keep it in the structure above.

- "Native" conveys the origination I'm after, but not the continuous perpetuation
- "Perpetual" is too eternal, as is "eternal" (I want to convey "until now")
- "Perennial" doesn't convey origination or, necessarily, continuousness
- "Longtime" has the same problems as "perennial"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

***"Lifelong" city dweller*** covers past and present.

Comment: Wow, that totally works!  I'm a little dismayed that the answer was so simple after pondering it for as long as I have, but that same simplicity makes it all the more perfect.  Thank you for being knowledgeable—and speedy!